# Anomalous non-award of a class badge

Tags: support, tag-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

A few months ago I noticed reaching the 100 vote/20 non-CW answer threshold for a tag and since then have exceeded these thresholds, but no class badge ever was awarded.  The threshold was first reached by retagging a question: perhaps that's the origin of the problem?

(I really don't care about this particular situation, and most likely am just misunderstanding the process, but I'm bringing this circumstance up because it could indicate some flaw deep in the badge-awarding algorithm, so perhaps others are affected without knowing it.)

Comment: Congratulations, you've encountered obscure badge rule #258: Tags only award tag badges if they have been applied to at least 100 questions.  See here for the juicy details: [List of all badges with full descriptions - Tag Badges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68395#68395)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `algorithm` tag for which you expected a badge only has [83 questions](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/algorithm).

The minimum requirement for any tag badge to be awarded is 100.  Once there are 100 questions with that tag the badge should be awarded.

Comment: Thanks: I suspected it was my misunderstanding and am glad that it doesn't reflect a problem in the system.

Comment: I did not know this... Interesting.